# SQL Select all nodes in a three level tree that match a criterion

Tags: postgresql

I have an PostgreSQL model (generated in the context of Django) that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE org (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  parent_id INTEGER,
  name CHARACTER VARYING(24),
  org_type  CHARACTER VARYING(8),
  country CHARACTER VARYING(2)
)

CREATE TABLE rate (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  org_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  rate DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  currency CHARACTER VARYING(3)
)
```

where org_type is one of "group", "company" and "branch". Every branch has a company, and only companies belong to a group. Given an arbitrary company or branch, and a country, I need to find all of the rates whose org_id is that of a company and branch that belongs to the same group and that are in the specified country. So, in the following diagram, for either company 123 (in Canada) or branch 124 (in Toronto), a search for rates with country = "US" would find rates belonging to the companies or branches in the box labeled "Selected":

[image]

I'm trying something like the following for companies, where `$1` is a country code and `$2` is an org ID:

```
SELECT rate.org_id, rate.rate, rate.currency
FROM rate, org
WHERE (
  org.country = $1 AND
  rate.org_id=org.id AND
  org.parent_id = $2
) OR (
  ...
```

and then I'm stuck, trying to figure out how to ask for the branches that belong to one of the companies that I just found. I'd really prefer one big WHERE clause that brings in all of the rates by *any* relevant organization, so that I don't have to hammer the DB with a whole bunch of queries.

*Edit*

Based on [lau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54064144/620679), I've tried an example ([SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/be28a/5)), but it's only returning rates for the organization that I'm starting with.

Comment: Just want to clarify that if user provide organisation id for group 122 and country US then there will be 3 rates in ur results and if country is CA then 2 results. Only 2 variables in query country code and organisation id which will always be of type group.

Comment: Yep, that's correct, although (as it turns out) only companies and branches have rates.

Comment: Answer to your edit: I have just done an edit and tested on your SQL fiddle. With the LEFT OUTER JOIN, you will see exactly where the recursion goes and you will need  to go to id 1 or 3 to get more than 1 rate returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Apply the criteria on `org` just like you did
2. Browse all the way **up/down** using your initial `org`(s) as the starting point
3. Combine the 2 sets with a `UNION`
4. `JOIN` with rates (below I have done a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to make it clear what is exactly included in the recursion).

Example:

```
WITH RECURSIVE SelectedOrg AS (
    SELECT * FROM org WHERE id = 4
),
BrowseOrg AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Direction, * FROM SelectedOrg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1, * FROM SelectedOrg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Direction, org.* FROM org JOIN BrowseOrg ON (direction = 1 and org.parent_id = BrowseOrg.id) OR (direction = -1 and org.id = BrowseOrg.parent_id)
)
SELECT DISTINCT rates.id, BrowseOrg.id, rates.rate FROM BrowseOrg LEFT OUTER JOIN rates ON org_id = BrowseOrg.id
```

This will be flexible enough to handle cases where you do not know what level of `org` you have selected (group, company or branch).
In the future, this also should be able to cope with a deeper hierarchy (if you ever add levels to it).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 queries with some sub query.

Let `company_org_ids = select id from org where country code = $1  and parent_id = $2`

`Select distinct rate.* from rate where orgid in ($3) or where orgid in (select id from org where parent_id in $3 and country_code =$1)`

Here $3 is `company_org_ids` result of first query.

Also this can be done with single query by replacing `$3` variable with first query.